# How to send JSON payload to create buttons with pymessenger Facebook chatbot

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating a Facebook messenger chatbot with `pymessenger`, `flask` and `wit.at`. I want to add buttons as options in my chatbot conversation.

For example

```
" Generic Offer 1"+"\n"+" Generic Offer 2"+"\n"+" Generic Offer 3"
```

is what I want to show up as a button to user instead of just text. So the user can select one offer. Facebook has the option to add buttons https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/ via JSON.

I want to do the similar thing. But I don't know how to do it. I can do simple text thing but now this, because I don't know JSON. As of now, my chatbot is replying via `bot.send_text_message(sender_id, response)`.

```
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()
    log(data)

    if data['object'] == 'page':
        for entry in data['entry']:
            for messaging_event in entry['messaging']:

                sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
                recipient_id = messaging_event['recipient']['id']

                if messaging_event.get('message'):
                    if 'text' in messaging_event['message']:
                        messaging_text = messaging_event['message']['text']
                    else:
                        messaging_text = 'no text'

                    response = None

                    entity, value = wit_response(messaging_text)

     if entity == 'newstype':
                            response = "OK. I will send you {} news".format(str(value))
                        elif entity == 'cust_greet':
                            response = get_message()
                        elif entity == 'cust_greet2':
                            response = get_message2()
                        elif entity == 'cust_offer':
                            #response = offer_response
                            response = " Generic Offer 1"+"\n"+" Generic Offer 2"+"\n"+" Generic Offer 3"+"\n"+" ️ for more offer enter your cust id"
                            #val_off = test.val_off

        bot.send_text_message(sender_id, response)
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy: For example:  " Generic Offer 1"+"\n"+" Generic Offer 2"+"\n"+" Generic Offer 3" I want to show this text as a button to user. So user can select one offer. Facebook has option to add button (like this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/) I want to do the similar thing. But I dont know how to do it. I can do simple text thing but now this, because I dont know json.

Comment: Hey @Jayjayyy: added. :)

Comment: @Jayjayyy: Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `bot.send_text_message`, the correct way to send the JSON payload is via [`bot.send_raw`](https://github.com/davidchua/pymessenger/blob/master/pymessenger/bot.py#L292). So using the example from [your link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/) you can test if it's working with something similar to:

```
payload = """{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"What do you want to do next?",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://www.example1.com",
            "title":"Visit Example 1"
          },
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://www.example2.com",
            "title":"Visit Example 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}"""
bot.send_raw(payload)
```

Don't forget to replace `<PSID>`.

Comment: But What I need to add to pass entries with payload in my code: `if messaging_event.get('message'):
                    if 'text' in messaging_event['message']:
                        messaging_text = messaging_event['message']['text']
                    else:
                        messaging_text = 'no text'

                    response = None`